# Error Adding custom menu to odoo 10, Error providing here: < parent="base.menu_sales" >

Tags: odoo-9, odoo-10

I dont know why it don't work, when I try the following it work!

```
<menuitem id="dietfacts_menu" action="product.product_template_actions_dietfacts" name="Diet Items" parent="base.menu_custom"/>
```

But, when I change the **parent** attribute to *base.menu_sales* It don't work!!

```
<menuitem id="dietfacts_menu" action="product.product_template_actions_dietfacts" name="Diet Items" parent="base.menu_sales"/>
```

on **Odoo 9**, the both codes work very well, but on **odoo 10**, only the first!!

please help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in the **XML ID** you are providing to the parent.

To get the correct XML id of the menu item go **Settings -> Dashboard -> Activate Developers Console**

Navigate to **Technical -> User Interface -> Menu Items**.

Locate the parent menu by searching for it. Open it up.
Click on the debugger menu present above and click over the **View Metadata** option.

This will show you the correct XML ID of the menu, which you can write in the parent option of the menuitem.
[image]

Hope it helps.
Thanks

Comment: thank you Sudhanshu Gupta!!!! I will not have similar problem next time!! this is my general solution!!! thanks!! don't forget to vote the question please!!!

Answer (score 1):

In Odoo 10, this menu is not in base module, but it is in sales_team module,
so you should write external id "**sales_team.menu_sales**" instead of "**base.menu_sales**"

```
<menuitem id="dietfacts_menu" action="product.product_template_actions_dietfacts" name="Diet Items" parent="sales_team.menu_sales"/>
```